# Nginx Workers auto vs mentioning a number

Tags: linux, nginx, ubuntu-14.04

Have been figuring out the right number for `worker_processes` and even though there has been some progress while mentioning custom value. A recent event has made me the question - What would be the ideal value for `worker_processes` should it be `auto` or should it be `number of processors * the number of cores` Have googled it and it isn't much of help.

Moreover, I am trying to understand the difference between mentioning an optimal number, ourself and setting it to auto.

Comment: As the docs explain, there is no single right answer. If there was, they would just hard code it and it wouldn't be configurable at all.

Comment: @MichaelHamptonI do understand that but I am looking into the difference that setting it to auto would bring in, in a server where there are fewer users wouldn't make a difference, but with the server where there are millions of users a month, even a smaller tweak can have an impact and hence the question.

Comment: nginx is not usually CPU bound. So whether there's an impact depends on what nginx is doing and how busy the server already was. You may not see any change at all.